# How to show all the columns data in full outer join

Tags: sql-server, join, query, cte, cross-join

I have 2 tables.

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

The Result is

[image: Output]

Issue is EnteredBy=23 is not displaying because I am using CT1.EnteredBy.
How to display CT11.EnteredBy value instead of NULL

The Actual Query I am using is given below

```
With CT1 As(
        Select C1.EnteredBy,CodingTimeInMin
              =Sum(ROUND(CAST(C1.CODINGTIME AS FLOAT)/(CAST(60 AS FLOAT)),4))
        from [dbo].[CodedDatas] C1
               INNER JOIN
               (Select Document_Id,Max(LastModified) As LastModified 
                from [DBO].[CODEDDATAS]
                Group By Document_Id) C2
                on C1.Document_ID=C2.Document_ID
                And C1.Coded=1 And C1.Revision=0 
                --And C1.LastModified=C2.LastModified
                group by C1.EnteredBy
        ),
        CT11 As(
        Select C1.EnteredBy,ReviewedTimeInMin=
               Sum(ROUND(CAST(C1.QATime AS FLOAT)/(CAST(60 AS FLOAT)),4))
        from [dbo].[CodedDatas] C1
        INNER JOIN
               (Select Document_Id,Max(LastModified) As LastModified 
        from [DBO].[CODEDDATAS]
                Group By Document_Id) C2
                on C1.Document_ID=C2.Document_ID 
                And C1.Coded=1 And C1.Revision=1
                And C1.LastModified=C2.LastModified
                group by C1.EnteredBy
        ),
        CT2 As(
        Select CodingTimeInHR=
        ROUND(CT1.CodingTimeInMin/CAST(60 AS FLOAT), 4) ,
        ReviewedTimeInHR=
         ROUND(CT11.ReviewedTimeInMin/CAST(60 AS FLOAT), 4) ,
        EnteredBy=CT1.EnteredBy
        from CT1
        full outer join CT11 on CT1.EnteredBy=CT11.EnteredBy
        ) 
        select * from CT2;
```

Comment: It looks like the projection defined by cte2 doesn't include any of the cte11 columns.

Comment: I did EnteredBy=IsNull(CT1.EnteredBy,CT11.EnteredBy) and it has now given the desired result

Comment: welcome to dba.se. Please instead of just putting the queries here, in a picture format, put the create table scripts and the inserts, then it is much easier to help you. check this out: [help me write this query in sql.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)